# Creating a multi-index dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Please consider these two dataframes that contain demographical info about a single zip code (10001):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([['Enrolled In Public School',2000 ], ['Enrolled In Private School', 100], ['Not Enrolled In School', 1]], columns = ['enrollment type', 'count'], index = ['10001', '10001','10001'])

df2 =  pd.DataFrame([12000], columns = ['population'], index = ['10001'])
```

df1 looks like:

```
        enrollment type             count
10001   Enrolled In Public School   2000
10001   Enrolled In Private School  100
10001   Not Enrolled In School      1
```

df2 looks like:

```
        population
10001   12000
```

How can I create a multi-index dataframe that looks like below? My goal is then to expand this dataframe for more zipcodes.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can first `reset_index()` on `df1` and `df2`, merge them together, and then use `pandas.pivot_table()`.

```
df1 = df1.reset_index()
df2 = df2.reset_index()

df = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left', on='index')

df.columns = ['zipcode', 'enrollment type', 'count', 'population']

df.pivot_table(columns=['enrollment type'], index=['zipcode', 'population'])
```

Result:

[Result Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fp8pg.png)

Comment: Thank you but this is not exactly what I need. This pivot table is not a multi-index dataframe

Comment: What do you mean "This pivot table is not a multi-index dataframe"? The resulting DataFrame has both a column _and_ an index MultiIndex. `MultiIndex([('10001', 12000)], names=['zipcode', 'population'])` and `MultiIndex([('count', 'Enrolled In Private School'), ('count',  'Enrolled In Public School'), ('count',     'Not Enrolled In School')], names=[None, 'enrollment type'])`

Comment: @HenryEcker Thanks for jumping in. I may be wrong but I just thought using a pivot table is not the right approach to building a multi-index dataframe (However, I understand that df.index does return a multi-index). I thought that a pivot table is more appropriate for a cross-tabulation analysis. So, in short, is this answer the best approach to my problem? Also, please note that there will be many multi-index columns similar to "enrollment type" in the actual df1 so I prefer an approach in which I don't have to type all column names when constructing the combined multi-index df, if possible.